# How to manage an active class <v-tabs> in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have `<v-tabs>` this kind:

```
<v-tabs
            fixed-tabs
            centered
            align-with-title
            height="55"
            class="d-flex align-end justify-center mt-0"
        >
          <v-tabs-slider color="pink" v-show="(searchClosed && !search)"></v-tabs-slider>
          <v-tab :disabled="!searchClosed" :to="{ name : 'home' }">Home</v-tab>
          <v-tab :disabled="!searchClosed" :to="{ name : 'premiers' }">Premiers</v-tab>
          <v-menu offset-y bottom max-height="500" v-model="genresMenu">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-tab @click="genresMenu = !genresMenu" bind="attrs" v-on="on">Genres</v-tab>
            </template>
            <v-list
                nav
                rounded
                max-width="800"
                align="center"
            >
              <v-list-item
                  v-for="genre in genres"
                  :key="genre.id"
                  :to="{ name : 'genre', params: { id: genre.id }}"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ genre.name }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </v-tabs>
```

The active class switches between the Home / Premiers tab as needed, but when you click on the link on the Genre tab, the active class is updated and returned to the Home tab. Can I somehow keep the Genre tab active after following the link inside v-list-item?
Example path: /genre/1

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```html
<template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
  <v-tab >
    <div @click="genresMenu = !genresMenu" bind="attrs" v-on="on">Genre</div>
  </v-tab>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me